# How to insert dependent modules into Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, ar.drone

I have a Parrot AR.Drone 2.0 running Ubuntu and I want to connect it to the single board computer using cable. There are no Ethernet ports on the drone so I decided to use USB-Ethernet adapter (D-Link DUB-E100). 
After entering `uname -a` in the terminal I get the following line:

```
Linux uclibc 2.6.32.9-g980dab2 #1 PREEMPT Mon Oct 6 11:50:23 CEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I followed [this](http://syntaxandsemantic.blogspot.com/2013/12/attaching-wifi-dongle-to-ar-drone-20.html) article and instead of module for wifi I used module for USB-Ethernet adapter.

This how I edited Makefile:

```
TARGET  = dub_e100
OBJS    = dub_e100.o
MDIR    = drivers/net/usb
KDIR    = /home/artemii/Downloads/linux

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /home/artemii/Downloads/linux/$(MDIR)

obj-m      := $(TARGET).o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)

install:
    su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).ko $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean

.PHONY: modules clean

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

After that I compiled the kernel with following lines:

```
make
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
make
```

Leter on I transfer generated 'dub_e100.ko' file into drone and ran the following command line:

```
insmod dube100.ko
```

Terminal threw an error `insmod: can't insert 'dub_e100.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter`.
Checking dmesg | tail gives:

```
usb 1-1:1.0: uevent
dub_e100: Unknown symbol mii_ethtool_sset
dub_e100: Unknown symbol mii_link_ok
dub_e100: Unknown symbol mii_nway_restart
dub_e100: Unknown symbol generic_mii_ioctl
dub_e100: Unknown symbol mii_ethtool_gset
```

I assume that adapter's module depends on mii module, so I generated `mii.ko` file with following makefile:

```
TARGET  = dub_e100
OBJS    = dub_e100.o
MDIR    = drivers/net/usb
KDIR    = /home/artemii/Downloads/linux

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /home/artemii/Downloads/linux/$(MDIR)

obj-m      := $(TARGET).o
obj-m += mii.o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)

install:
    su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).ko $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean

.PHONY: modules clean

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

After that I consiquately run `mii.ko` and `dube100.ko` on the drone. All the modules visible in `lsmod`. But after inserting the adapter to the drone it crushes and reboots. After reboot this modules dessapiar from `lsmod`. 
Is there something I am doing wrong? I might generated or ran modules improperly.

Comment: What do you want to achive by a rule `$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)`? If dereference variables, it becomes  `dub_e100.o: dub_e100.o` which is *useless* (or it even could harm the kernel build system).

Answer (score 0):

`insmod` does not handle module dependencies.  It's [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/insmod) says:

> **insmod** is a trivial program to insert a module into the kernel. Most users will want to use [**modprobe(8)**](https://manpages.debian.org/modprobe) instead, which is more clever and can handle module dependencies.

Note that you may have to run [`depmod`](https://manpages.debian.org/depmod) before the `modprobe` automatic dependency loading works as intended.